# Conditional mean clarification

Tags: probability

Considering a two-dimensional space $S$ of two random variables $X, Y$, is the following equality true or not for a p.m.f $f(x,y)$

$\sum_{(x,y) \in S} yf(x,y) = \mu_y$

I am having difficulty reconciling this with the definition that $\mu_y = \sum_{y \in S_y} yf_Y(y)$ where $f_Y(y)  = \sum_{x \in S_X} f(x,y)$

Comment: If you view the summation as a double summation, like $\displaystyle E[Y] = \sum_{y\in S_Y}y \sum_{x \in S_X} f(x, y)$, is it better?

Comment: @BGM what if the support is not rectangular, but a collection of points.

Comment: Even the support is not rectangular, it stills hold - $f(x, y) = 0$ will handle this. If you really dislike the zero terms in the summand, you replace $S_X$ by $S_X(y)$ to restrict that..